Datamapper Transform: Access a variables that's stored in a list inside another list
In my intergration procedure I call an expression set, which returns me a value. Yet this value is nested in a list inside a list.
How can I fetch the calculated price from this json? I've tried traversing up with the |1 but this doesn't seem to work.

output|1:calculationResults|1:calculatedPrice

{
        "OutputPrice": {
          "output": [
            {
              "calculationResults": [
                {
                  "ID": "ProductPriceCalculation",
                  "calculatedPrice": 100
                }
              ],
              "aggregationResults": {}
            }
          ],
          "errorCode": "INVOKE-200",
          "error": "OK"
        }

EDIT




Output from Loopblock after running the IP
 {
"output_cleanUpPayload": {
  "Products": {
    "gridId": 123123
  },
  "outputFromLoopBlock": [
    {
      "calculationResults": [
        {
          "ID": "ProductPriceCalculation",
          "calculatedPrice": 0
        }
      ],
      "aggregationResults": {}
    }
  ]
},
"output_calculatePrice": {
  "output": [
    {
      "calculationResults": [
        {
          "ID": "ProductPriceCalculation",
          "calculatedPrice": 0
        }
      ],
      "aggregationResults": {}
    }
  ],
  "errorCode": "INVOKE-200",
  "error": "OK"
},


The problem seems to have been the response from the Expression Set Action. Without re-serializing the response the value inside the response couldn't be fetched. If you set in the Remote Options re-serialize to TRUE it works.
See Salesforce documentation here.


You almost got it:
OutputPrice:output|1:calculationResults|1:calculatedPrice

This will give you 100. I also tested:
OutputPrice:output:calculationResults:calculatedPrice

and that also works, but I suggest using the pipe symbol especially if there are more than one list entry.
Good luck!

Thanks! The main issue here was, i was working with a Data mapper transform, for which this does NOT work it seems. It does work correctly by using an extract mapper.

There are always more than one way to get to where you want to be when it comes to Omnistudio :-P

Sorry I stand corrected, whilst implemented in my IP. It does not work. Here's what happens. OutputPrice:output|1 still returns gets me inside the first list -- whenever I go one level deeper it stops returning anything. e.g. OutputPrice:output|1:calculationResults|1:calculatedPrice returns nothing. I am running: 1 x Expression Set Action which gets send to a data mapper extract. The whole thing is running in a loop block, in case that makes a difference.

@jvb will you be able to update your question with screenshots please? Adding the IP as well as where you send the JSON to the datamapper, where you specified the path in the datamapper etc. Just so that I, and others, are able to better visualise/replicate your scenario

Thanks. I've added screens above.
